# A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderRepaintBoundary

Tags: flutter, dart

This may be a simple question, but I couldn't find the answer. When I used this code:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
                key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
```

I got error:

> A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of
> type 'RenderRepaintBoundary'.?

It's fine When I use dart version: `2.7.0`, makes problem when I changed it to `2.12.0`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To solve the error, just do this:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
            key.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
```

This way, you will cast it as a RenderRepaintBoundary.

Comment: Is there any other solution rather than using a cast?

Answer (score 6):

To avoid **`The method 'findRenderObject' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.`** error, add an exclamation mark to avoid null like this:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myKey= new GlobalKey();
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = myKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
```